# Como pegar para passar o valor de um input para a url

Tags: php

Bom dia para todos, sou iniciante em php e estou montando uma loja virtual aqui no meu estágio, bom é o seguinte, já consigo criar a sessão com o carrinho e excluir ela sem problemas, eu não estou conseguindo alterar a quantidade que o usuário informou e ele atualizar o carrinho, segue abaixo o código que eu uso para criar o carrinho

```
if (isset($_SESSION['carrinho'])){
$_SESSION['carrinho'][base64_decode($_GET['id'])] = $_POST['qtde'];
}else{
     $_SESSION['carrinho'] = array();
     $_SESSION['carrinho'][base64_decode($_GET['id'])] = $_POST['qtde'];
 }
```

Segue abaixo o código da página do carrinho, não sei pra que lado ir

```
<?php 
include_once './cabecalho.php';
//FAZER BACALHAU PARA MONTAR UMA TABELA COM OS ITENS E TER AS SEGUINTES OPÇÕES:
// =>ALTERAR QUANTIDADE;
// =>EXCLUIR PRODUTO - OK 
// TER UM CAMPO PARA FINALIZAR O PEDIDO
// MONTAR GRID COM OS PRODUTOS - OK
$wLista='';
$wCont=1;
foreach ($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $produto_id => $qtde) {
//AQUI FAZER BACHALHAU PARA PEGAR OS PRODUTOS DO BANCO
$objProduto = new Produtos();
$objProduto->id=$produto_id;
$produto = $objProduto->SelectUm();

$wLista.='<tr>
       <td>'.$wCont.'</td>
       <td><input type="hidden" name="produto_id[]" value="'.$produto_id.'">'.$produto->nome.'</td>
       <td><input type="text" value="'.$qtde.'" name="qtde[]" id="qtde"></td>
       <td>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" name="alterar" href="carrinho.php?alterar='.base64_encode($produto_id).'"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Atualizar </a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" name="excluir" href="carrinho.php?excluir='.base64_encode($produto_id).'"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Excluir </a>
        </td>
     </tr>';
$wCont++;
}
unset($produto);
if ($_GET){
if (isset($_GET['excluir'])){
    $id = intval(base64_decode($_GET['excluir']));
    if(isset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$id])){
        unset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$id]);
        header("Location: carrinho.php");
        exit();
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['alterar'])){
    //PERCORRER OS ITENS DA VARIAVEL SESSION['carrinho']
    //DEPOIS QUE ACHAR O ITEM, ALTERAR A QTDE NA SESSION 
    //E RECARREGAR PÁGINA
    $id = intval(base64_decode($_GET['alterar']));
    foreach ($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $produto_id =>$qtde){
        if ($produto_id===$id){
            $qtde = $_GET['qtde[]'];
            echo '<script>alert("encontrei !!!!!")</script>';
        }   
    }
}
}
if ($_POST){
$wLista='';
foreach ($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $produto_id => $qtde) {
    //AQUI FAZER BACHALHAU PARA PEGAR OS PRODUTOS DO BANCO
    $objProduto = new Produtos();
    $objProduto->id=$produto_id;
    $produto = $objProduto->SelectUm();

$wLista.='<tr>
       <td>'.$wCont.'</td>
       <td><input type="hidden" name="produto_id[]" value="'.$produto_id.'">'.$produto->nome.'</td>
       <td><input type="text" value="'.$qtde.'" name="qtde[]" id="qtde"></td>
       <td>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" name="alterar" href="carrinho.php?alterar='.base64_encode($produto_id).'?qtde="><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Atualizar </a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" name="excluir"  href="carrinho.php?excluir='.base64_encode($produto_id).'"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Excluir </a>
        </td>
     </tr>';
$wCont++;
}
unset($produto);
}
?>
<form role="form" action="finalizaCarrinho.php" method="post" >
<div class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Nro Item</th>
              <th>Produto</th>
              <th>Qtde</th>
              <th>Ação</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <?php echo $wLista;?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
      <div class="row text-right">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <input type="submit" value="Finalizar Pedido" class="btn btn-primary">
          <a  href="vitrine.php" class="btn btn-primary">Continuar comprando</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
<?php 
include_once './rodape.php';?>
```

não consigo é fazer ele atualizar a sessão com a qtde que o usuário informa la no input, fico grato pela ajuda de todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está que não há método GET com o parametro `qtde[]`.

**O erro é:**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" name="alterar" href="carrinho.php?alterar=base?qtde=">
```

Em única linha há vários erros, somente um `?` pode ser utilizado e o `qtde` não é `qtde[]` chamado no PHP.

**Pseudo-Solução:**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" name="alterar" href="carrinho.php?alterar=123456&qtde[]=1">
```

O `&` substituiu o `?` no segundo parametro e o nome.

**Isso resolve? Não sei!**

É necessário que exista  um javascript para pegar o dado do campo `qtde[]` para que seja inserido no URL.

Jquery + HTML para resolver:

```
<input type="text" value="'.$qtde.'" name="qtde" idproduto="{BASE64}">
<!-- adcionado idproduto e name alterado -->

<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" name="alterar" href="carrinho.php?alterar={BASE64}&qtde[]={QUANTIDADE PADRAO}" id="alterar_{BASE64}">
<-- id adicionado com padrão alterar_ -->

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name=qtde]').change(function() {
  id = $(this).attr(idproduto);
  url = 'carrinho.php?alterar='+id+'&qtde[]='+$(this).val();
  $("#alterar_"+id).attr("href", url);
  });
});

</script>
```

Precisará de algumas adaptações e testes.

**Ideia:**

> Quando o input for alterado ele pega o `idproduto` (que é igual ao ID do
>   produto!) e irá inserir o novo URL, com a alteração de quantidade e
>   com o ID do produto, quando clicar no link haverá ambos os atributos.

O ideal é mudar isto tudo e fazer um `FORM GET` ou `POST` ao invés de `HREF`

Answer (score -2):

Você não pode usar as de `$_GET` quando houver o `method="post"` no seu formulário.

Comment: No caso não é post, porque o `GET` está embutido no URL no `<a href=''></a>`

Comment: E não é verdade, se eu fizer um `<form method="POST" action="meu.php?a=10">` o `$_GET['a']` vai retornar 10, independente do método. Até imagino que você quis ser específico no contexto da pergunta, mas é bom não deixar margem pra enganos.